# Parse XML schema with imported namespaces

Tags: r, xml, xsd, libxml2

I have a complex [XML schema](https://github.com/miquelcaceres/VegX/tree/master/vegxschema) consisting of multiple namespaces defined in different files. Below is a figure created in XSD Diagram that shows a small part of the schema.

[image: Tree View of the Schema in XSD Diagram]

Note that `party` is of type `partyType`, which is defined in a different namespace than `parties`. The (simplified) XML for `parties` in the main file (`veg.xsd`) looks like this:

```
...
<xsd:element name="parties" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>...</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="party" type="misc:partyType" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation source="EML" xml:lang="en">...</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
```

Now, my aim is to derive the hierarchy of elements for the entire schema (across namespaces), pretty much like in the figure above. However, when I parse `veg.xsd` in R, I have no access to the imported namespaces. For example, when list all elements having a name attribute, I only get the names of elements defined in `veg.xsd`.

```
library(xml2)
def_xsd = read_xml("vegx_schema/veg.xsd")
xml_find_all(def_xsd, "//xsd:element") %>% 
  xml_attr("name") %>%
  length()

[1] 52 # Should be much larger
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing source schema documents is not easy, as you're discovering.

It's much better to process a compiled schema via an API.

I don't know what libxml2 offers in this way. If you can use Java then Xerces offers a Java API to the compiled schema, and Saxon allows you to export the compiled schema as an SCM file (which is XML, but unlike the source schema it's all assembled into a single document that's much easier to process).

Comment: Oh, that's bad news. However, the fact that libxml2 can validate xml files against the schema makes me think that it does know how to put the parts together. I'll leave the question open for a bit, maybe someone has another solution.

Comment: Sure, libxml2 knows how to compile a schema into some internal structured representation. What I don't know is whether it offers users/applications any access to that representation via an API. Looking at `http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html` it seems it might, but that looks very low-level.